# Master-slave replication; read-splitting strategy

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave

We're close to requiring replication on our MySQL database, and I'm looking for a bit of clarification on the best strategy. Hopefully this is still specific enough a question to be asked here.

We currently have 1 DB for our application which is fairly read-intensive. I'm thinking of starting with a simple master-slave setup where reads will be split around 40% to the master and 60% to the slave, based on some rudimentary load-balancing logic within the application.

I've said a 40-60 split as there are some occasional reads which I know will take a long time to execute, potentially a minute or longer. Rather than load balancing these reads, I plan on always directing these to the master. I'd rather have the master do the work and and give the slave time to catch up, rather than potentially introduce replication lag on simpler queries. (When we can advance to multiple slaves, we'll have one dedicated to these intensive queries).

So I guess my question is - does this sound like a sane plan, or if not what would be a better alternative?

---

Edit in response to the comments below:

@Romain - A large part of the application involves signed-in users posting, commenting and replying, so for these operations stale data needs to be avoided where possible.

@Jaydee - yes, I've built in a weighting value for each server so I can easily change the read % if needed.

Comment: If it's read-intensive, low-write, the risk of introducing a lag on the slave because of it spending time on "long" queries is fairly low... And you didn't mention whether you needed "absolute consistency" on the reads? (e.g. is it OK if a client reads stale data every so often?)

Comment: Sounds like a plan to start with, you may want to tune the split between master and slave as once you can see how the utilisation works out.

Comment: Thanks, replied above in an edit.

Comment: I would avoid the use of the master for slow queries. Usually if a query is very slow uses hard disk, which then impacts on all queries in writing, by altering the performance of the DB and then of the site. Rather than I would devote a slave to those queries.